# how to display camera on Android phone by using phonegap

Tags: android, cordova, camera

I want to capture an image by using phonegap on Android phone. I try the code posted on Phonegap page but the camera does not appear. Any help is appreciated.Thank you very much.

It is the display on my phone

[image: It is the display on my phone, there is no camera]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Capture Photo</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-1.6.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

    var pictureSource;   // picture source
    var destinationType; // sets the format of returned value 

    // Wait for Cordova to connect with the device
    //
    document.addEventListener("deviceready",onDeviceReady,false);

    // Cordova is ready to be used!
    //
    function onDeviceReady() {
        pictureSource=navigator.camera.PictureSourceType;
        destinationType=navigator.camera.DestinationType;
    }

    // Called when a photo is successfully retrieved
    //
    function onPhotoDataSuccess(imageData) {
      // Uncomment to view the base64 encoded image data
      // console.log(imageData);

      // Get image handle
      //
      var smallImage = document.getElementById('smallImage');

      // Unhide image elements
      //
      smallImage.style.display = 'block';

      // Show the captured photo
      // The inline CSS rules are used to resize the image
      //
      smallImage.src = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;
    }

    // Called when a photo is successfully retrieved
    //
    function onPhotoURISuccess(imageURI) {
      // Uncomment to view the image file URI 
      // console.log(imageURI);

      // Get image handle
      //
      var largeImage = document.getElementById('largeImage');

      // Unhide image elements
      //
      largeImage.style.display = 'block';

      // Show the captured photo
      // The inline CSS rules are used to resize the image
      //
      largeImage.src = imageURI;
    }

    // A button will call this function
    //
    function capturePhoto() {
      // Take picture using device camera and retrieve image as base64-encoded string
      navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoDataSuccess, onFail, { quality: 50,
        destinationType.DATA_URL });
    }

    // A button will call this function
    //
    function capturePhotoEdit() {
      // Take picture using device camera, allow edit, and retrieve image as base64-encoded string  
      navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoDataSuccess, onFail, { quality: 20, allowEdit: true,
        destinationType.DATA_URL });
    }

    // A button will call this function
    //
    function getPhoto(source) {
      // Retrieve image file location from specified source
      navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoURISuccess, onFail, { quality: 50, 
        destinationType: destinationType.FILE_URI,
        sourceType: source });
    }

    // Called if something bad happens.
    // 
    function onFail(message) {
      alert('Failed because: ' + message);
    }

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button onclick="capturePhoto();">Capture Photo</button> <br>
    <button onclick="capturePhotoEdit();">Capture Editable Photo</button> <br>
    <button onclick="getPhoto(pictureSource.PHOTOLIBRARY);">From Photo Library</button><br>
    <button onclick="getPhoto(pictureSource.SAVEDPHOTOALBUM);">From Photo Album</button><br>
    <img style="display:none;width:60px;height:60px;" id="smallImage" src="" />
    <img style="display:none;" id="largeImage" src="" />
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What do you see in "adb logcat" when you click one of the camera buttons?

Comment: Thank you, I solved the problem. I try Phonegap1.0.0 and it works. I dont know why. Is there something wrong with Phonegap1.6?

Comment: It would be nice to figure out what the problem was in 1.6. Can you do the logcat step?

Answer (score 6):

Both your `capturePhoto()` and `capturePhotoEdit()` functions need to have the `destinationType` updated.

```
navigator.camera.getPicture(
    onPhotoDataSuccess,
    onFail,
    {
        quality: 50,
        destinationType.DATA_URL
    }
);
```

should be like this,

```
navigator.camera.getPicture(
    onPhotoDataSuccess,
    onFail,
    {
        quality: 50,
        destinationType: destinationType.DATA_URL
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you Add permission and Camera feature on your AndroidMenifest file?
If you didn't add then try again.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code change the cordova version.
Now you have "cordova-1.6.0.js"
you should change it to "cordova-2.5.0.js"
I think it will work after that.
like this

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-2.5.0.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have been having the same issue, I've got the getPhoto() function working now,  but still can't get the cameraPhoto() or cameraPhotoEdit() functions working. I have done pretty much everything listen in this post and more.

Oh and you could try some of the solutions listed here:

[Phonegap Camera API Cannot Read Property data url of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22834145/phonegap-camera-api-cannot-read-property-data-url-of-undefined)