# Phonegap Camera API - Cannot read property 'DATA_URL' of undefined

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, android-camera, phonegap-build

I am creating an Android app using Phonegap.

I have installed phonegap using the commands on their website.

Everything is up and running with the SDK and Emulator.

Now when I run the example camera script from their website to get it working before I start cusotmising it.

Everytime I run the code below (even though I have the file linked to phonegap.js) it keeps throwing an error. I mean the script runs as far as the HTML and showing the buttons, but when the button is clicked nothing happens and in the log it says: Cannot read property 'DATA_URL' of undefined.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="no-js">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
        <!-- WARNING: for iOS 7, remove the width=device-width and height=device-height attributes. See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-4323 -->
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="phonegap.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/foundation.css" />
        <script src="js/vendor/modernizr.js"></script>
        <title>Retouch</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
        var pictureSource;   // picture source
        var destinationType; // sets the format of returned value 

        // Wait for PhoneGap to connect with the device
        //
        document.addEventListener("deviceready",onDeviceReady,false);

        // PhoneGap is ready to be used!
        //
        function onDeviceReady() {
            pictureSource=navigator.camera.PictureSourceType;
            destinationType=navigator.camera.DestinationType;
        }

        // Called when a photo is successfully retrieved
        //
        function onPhotoDataSuccess(imageData) {
          // Get image handle
          //
          var smallImage = document.getElementById('smallImage');

          // Unhide image elements
          //
          smallImage.style.display = 'block';

          // Show the captured photo
          // The inline CSS rules are used to resize the image
          //
          smallImage.src = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;
        }

        // Called when a photo is successfully retrieved
        //
        function onPhotoFileSuccess(imageData) {
          // Get image handle
          console.log(JSON.stringify(imageData));

          // Get image handle
          //
          var smallImage = document.getElementById('smallImage');

          // Unhide image elements
          //
          smallImage.style.display = 'block';

          // Show the captured photo
          // The inline CSS rules are used to resize the image
          //
          smallImage.src = imageData;
        }

        // Called when a photo is successfully retrieved
        //
        function onPhotoURISuccess(imageURI) {
          // Uncomment to view the image file URI 
          // console.log(imageURI);

          // Get image handle
          //
          var largeImage = document.getElementById('largeImage');

          // Unhide image elements
          //
          largeImage.style.display = 'block';

          // Show the captured photo
          // The inline CSS rules are used to resize the image
          //
          largeImage.src = imageURI;
        }

        // A button will call this function
        //
        function capturePhoto() {
          navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoDataSuccess, onFail, { quality: 50,
            destinationType: destinationType.DATA_URL });
        }

        function capturePhotoEdit() {
          navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoDataSuccess, onFail, { quality: 20, allowEdit: true,
            destinationType: destinationType.DATA_URL });
        }

        // A button will call this function
        //
        function getPhoto(source) {
          // Retrieve image file location from specified source
          navigator.Camera.getPicture(onPhotoURISuccess, onFail, {
         quality: 50, 
         destinationType: navigator.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
         sourceType: pictureSource
    });

        // Called if something bad happens.
        // 
        function onFail(message) {
          alert('Failed because: ' + message);
        }

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
      <!-- Navigation bar -->
        <div class="fixed">
          <nav class="top-bar fixed" data-topbar>
            <ul class="title-area">
              <li class="name">
                <h1 class="navmsg">
                  <script>
                  var Digital=new Date()
                  var hours=Digital.getHours()

                  if (hours>=5&&hours<=11)
                  document.write('<b>Good Morning.</b>')
                  else if (hours==12)
                  document.write('<b>Good Afternoon.</b>')
                  else if (hours>=13&&hours<=17)
                  document.write('<b>Good Afternoon.</b>')
                  else if (hours>=18&&hours<=20)
                  document.write('<b>Good Evening.</b>')
                  else if (hours>=21&&hours<=11)
                  document.write('<b>Hello!</b>')
                  else
                  document.write('<b>Hello!</b>')
                  </script>
                </h1>
              </li>
              <li class="toggle-topbar menu-icon"><a href="#">Account</a></li>
            </ul>
          </nav>
        </div>

        <button onclick="capturePhotoWithData();">Capture Photo With Image Data</button> <br>
        <button onclick="capturePhotoWithFile();">Capture Photo With Image File URI</button> <br>
        <button onclick="getPhoto(pictureSource.PHOTOLIBRARY);">From Photo Library</button><br>
        <button onclick="getPhoto(pictureSource.SAVEDPHOTOALBUM);">From Photo Album</button><br>
        <img style="display:none;width:60px;height:60px;" id="smallImage" src="" />
        <img style="display:none;" id="largeImage" src="" />

        <script type="text/javascript" src="phonegap.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
        <script src="js/vendor/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="js/foundation.min.js"></script>
        <script>
          $(document).foundation();
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            app.initialize();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>`
```

I have tried to use the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="phonegap.js"></script>
```

and

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
```

Nothing seems to work.

I have changed the following in capturePhoto() and capturePhotoEdit() from:

```
destinationType.DATA_URL
```

to

```
Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL
```

Still no luck with the functionality. I suspect it has something to do with the cordova plugin and phonegap, as I only have phonegap.js included in the script. I'm also reading about settings in the config.xml, which I have done through command line (unless I have done it wrong) following the docs.

I have built the application by CL:

```
phonegap build android
```

The following code with cordova-2.5.0.js and destinationType.FILE_URI added has successfully enabled the getPhoto() functions and allows me to display the photos in library/album.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="no-js">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
        <!-- WARNING: for iOS 7, remove the width=device-width and height=device-height attributes. See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-4323 -->
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="phonegap.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/foundation.css" />
        <script src="js/vendor/modernizr.js"></script>
        <title>Retouch</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-2.5.0.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

        var pictureSource;   // picture source
        var destinationType; // sets the format of returned value 

        // Wait for Cordova to connect with the device
        //
        document.addEventListener("deviceready",onDeviceReady,false);

        // Cordova is ready to be used!
        //
        function onDeviceReady() {
            pictureSource=navigator.camera.PictureSourceType;
            destinationType=navigator.camera.DestinationType;
        }

        // Called when a photo is successfully retrieved
        //
        function onPhotoDataSuccess(imageData) {
            // Uncomment to view the base64 encoded image data
            //alert(imageData);  

            // Get image handle
            //
            var smallImage = document.getElementById('smallImage');
            // Unhide image elements
            //
            smallImage.style.display = 'block';

            // Show the captured photo
            // The inline CSS rules are used to resize the image
            //
            smallImage.src = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;
        }

        // Called when a photo is successfully retrieved
        //
        function onPhotoURISuccess(imageURI) {
            alert("inside large image")
            // Uncomment to view the image file URI 
            // console.log(imageURI);

           // Get image handle
           //
            var largeImage = document.getElementById('largeImage');

          // Unhide image elements
          //
            largeImage.style.display = 'block';

          // Show the captured photo
          // The inline CSS rules are used to resize the image
          //
            largeImage.src = imageURI;
        }

        // A button will call this function
        //
        function capturePhoto() {
          // Take picture using device camera and retrieve image as base64-encoded string
            navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoDataSuccess, onFail, { quality: 50,
            destinationType: destinationType.FILE_URI });
        }

        // A button will call this function
        //
        function capturePhotoEdit() {
          // Take picture using device camera, allow edit, and retrieve image as base64-encoded string  
            navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoDataSuccess, onFail,
            { quality: 20, allowEdit: true,
            destinationType: destinationType.FILE_URI });
        }

        // A button will call this function
        //
        function getPhoto(source) {
          // Retrieve image file location from specified source
            navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoURISuccess, onFail, { quality: 50, 
            destinationType: destinationType.FILE_URI,
            sourceType: source });
        }


        // Called if something bad happens.
        // 
        function onFail(message) {
            alert('Failed because: ' + message);
        }

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
      <!-- Navigation bar -->
        <div class="fixed">
          <nav class="top-bar fixed" data-topbar>
            <ul class="title-area">
              <li class="name">
                <h1 class="navmsg">
                  <script>
                  var Digital=new Date()
                  var hours=Digital.getHours()

                  if (hours>=5&&hours<=11)
                  document.write('<b>Good Morning.</b>')
                  else if (hours==12)
                  document.write('<b>Good Afternoon.</b>')
                  else if (hours>=13&&hours<=17)
                  document.write('<b>Good Afternoon.</b>')
                  else if (hours>=18&&hours<=20)
                  document.write('<b>Good Evening.</b>')
                  else if (hours>=21&&hours<=11)
                  document.write('<b>Hello!</b>')
                  else
                  document.write('<b>Hello!</b>')
                  </script>
                </h1>
              </li>
              <li class="toggle-topbar menu-icon"><a href="#">Account</a></li>
            </ul>
          </nav>
        </div>

        <button onclick="capturePhotoWithData();">Capture Photo With Image Data</button> <br>
        <button onclick="capturePhotoWithFile();">Capture Photo With Image File URI</button> <br>
        <button onclick="getPhoto(pictureSource.PHOTOLIBRARY);">From Photo Library</button><br>
        <button onclick="getPhoto(pictureSource.SAVEDPHOTOALBUM);">From Photo Album</button><br>
        <img style="display:none;width:60px;height:60px;" id="smallImage" src="" />
        <img style="display:none;" id="largeImage" src="" />

        <script type="text/javascript" src="phonegap.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
        <script src="js/vendor/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="js/foundation.min.js"></script>
        <script>
          $(document).foundation();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I tried adding 'destinationType.FILE_URI' to capturePhoto() and capturePhotoEdit() functions, but they still don't seem to work.

I have now tried the following three types:

```
destinationType.FILE_URI
destinationType.DATA_URI
Camera.desitnationType.DATA_URI
```

None of them seem to make a difference.

Answer (score 3):

That is a Javascript error. You are trying to access a property of an undefined variable. This line (in the `capturePhoto` and `capturePhotoEdit` methods):

```
destinationType.DATA_URL
```

should be:

```
Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL
```

One more thing: With Cordova it is always good to have the docs at hand, and have a look at them each time you are using a new plugin, or when you upgrade to a newer version (they tend to change the API frequently, hence the examples found in Google usually show legacy code). Here you have the [Camera plugin documentation](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-camera/blob/dev/doc/index.md).

Comment: Should I include cordova.js or phonegap.js? It hasn't automatically included cordova.js in my project directory since I created the app using phonegap commands.

Comment: I used to create the projects using the template sample projects, so I'm not familiar with the new CLI commands. But since the cordova.js is platform specific, and the `create` command does not have the platform as argument, I guess it will be added later in the `build` command.

Comment: So I wouldn't need to add it manually? It will be taken care of via build.xml? Do I need to add anything in the build file as I've manually added the plugin line for cordova into my config.xml file.

Comment: Dude, I copied pasted your 'Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL', but it should be and 'I' at the end.

Comment: According to the docs of both phonegap and cordova, the possible values are DATA_URL, FILE_URI and NATIVE_URI.

Answer (score 1):

In my case when I pause the execution Camera has getPicture() method but not DestinationType and PictureSourceType propreties.

```
$scope.tomarFoto = function(){
$ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
  var options = {
    quality: 50,
    destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
    sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA
  };

  $cordovaCamera.getPicture(options).then(function (imageData) {
    $scope.cameraimage = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;
  }, function (err) {
    console.log('Failed because: ' + message);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATED**
Just I got recently the same problem.
If did you add the camera plugin and all the permissions needed, mainly you did all the [Phonegap Api](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.5.0/cordova_camera_camera.md.html) steps. I think you'r solution pass for go to you'r project folder and execute `phonegap build` or `phonegap build app_platform`.
First save you'r project data cause that command line reset the estructure of the project and delete the files you add.

Make me know if that works for you too, good luck.

Comment: I didn't do nothing with Cordova per say but I installed Phonegap through terminal, created a project, then implemented the camera script to a file called camera.html. I added the JS script as is and ran the script. The log keeps bringing up that error for the four functions.

Comment: I ran 'phonegap build android' and the package was built successfully, but still no success in accessing the camera.

Comment: Then it's just a diferent problem that shoots the same error

Comment: I have got the library and album function working, but the camera still doesn't work.

Comment: Try that at last chance: Find `camera.js` and import to you'r html like `phonegap.js`

Comment: I don't have a camera.js file, I only made camera.html and used the index.js within it.

Comment: And for that didn't works u must have a plugins folder to you'r www project folder with in the camere plugin folder and in that again another www folder with in the js files

Comment: No I don't have a camera.js just an index.js, which I have included in my script.

Comment: While you can't find you'r `camera.js` or you do not have it in you'r project you will not get this working.

Comment: I have added camera.js and included it in the html file, yet it still doesn't work. I have made sure all dependencies are there, as well as permissions in application and plugin in config.